# How to activate 2 gameobjects randomly?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this code but looks like the random is activating the same gameobject. How can I be sure that not the same will be activated? For example, this code activate 2 gameobjects but sometimes just only one, because the random picked the same gameobjects twice.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2; i++)
{
    int index = Random.Range(0, EyeButtonArray.Length);
    EyeButtonArray[index].SetActive(true);
}
```

Comment: You really don't need a loop for only 2 things. Best option is probably to create a temporary array of all the objects minus the first choice then pick from the new list.

Comment: @DerekC. `You really don't need a loop for only 2 things.` .. for now maybe .. but with a loop it is maintainable and scalable according to any later desires ;)

Comment: @derHugo then put it in a loop later? Do what you need now and don't act like it can't change.

Comment: @DerekC. Well, yes .. or directly make it good right away and do not need to even think about if it is happening for one, two or thousand objects ^^ Ok for single and two objects you might argue about overhead .. but from the maintainance perspective it totally makes sense to use a loop starting from two elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can shuffle your container randomly and pick the first two elements.

```
int wanted = 2;
int[] nums = System.Linq.Enumerable.Range(0, EyeButtonArray.Length).ToArray();
System.Random rnd = new System.Random();

nums = nums.OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();
for(int x = 0; x < 2; ++x)
    EyeButtonArray[nums[x]].SetActive(true);
```

Another solution using a `HashSet` is to keep track of the elements you have picked and keep generating until you pick a unique one.

```
HashSet<int> RandomElementIdx = new HashSet<int>();
int picked = 0;
int wanted = 2;

while(picked < wanted)
{
    int index = Random.Range(0, EyeButtonArray.Length);
    
    if(RandomElementIdx.Contains(index))
        continue;
        
    RandomElementIdx.Add(index);
    EyeButtonArray[index].SetActive(true);
    ++picked;
}
```

The above snippet is assuming your list is greater than or equal to `wanted`. If it is less, it will result in an infinite loop. It is also not exactly efficient as it will continually try to spawn new numbers until it randomly hits one not used.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but Unity is saying that System.Linq.Range is not valid. I am trying to find why. I already add using System.Linq; on the top of the file.

Comment: @Khrys Oops sorry I had deleted an important part with an edit. Fixed now.

Comment: Thanks, mate. That fixed that line. I am also having an warning for nums.Swap saying 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Swap' and no accessible extension method 'Swap' accepting a first argument of type 'int[]' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). Tthis was showing since the original post, sorry to not bring that. I am trying to find why. Thanks again.

Comment: Oops yep made another mistake from editing. Swap is used for Lists. You can swap your container to a list. If you want to use an array, you can use a direct swap of storing a temp variable. I'll update the answer to use it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That really helped me out.

Comment: Note that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68014320/7111561) is probably way more efficient ;)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want is

- You have a list/array of objects
- You want to enable the next two random ones of them
- (optionally - not sure on this) you want to disable the two current ones

You could simply "shuffle" your array and then enable the two first of the now shuffled items like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

// OPTIONAL (but I thought makes sense)
// store the currently enabled objects to also be able to disable them later
// when you enable the next pair
private GameObject[] _currentEnabled;

public void EnableTwoRandom()
{
    // OPTIONAL (but I thought makes sense)
    // if exists first disable the last selected two buttons
    if(_currentEnabled!=null)
    {
        foreach(var item in _currentEnabled)
        {
            item.SetActive(false);
        }
    } 

    // Pick two random buttons
    // This first "shuffles" the buttons and then simply takes the
    // first two random elements
    _currentEnabled = EyeButtonArray.OrderBy(i => Random.value).Take(2).ToArray();

    // enable the new two random buttons
    foreach(var item in toEnable)
    {
        item.SetActive(true);
    }
}
```

See

- [`IEnumerable.OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby)
- [`Random.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html)
- [`IEnumerable.Take`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.take)

---

if additionally you want to be sure that the new selected buttons are also not equal to the previous ones you could add

```
// Pick two random buttons
if(_currentEnabled != null)
{
    // if there already exists a previous selection
    // then exclude this selection from the available options first
    _currentEnabled = EyeButtonArray.Except(_currentEnabled).OrderBy(i => Random.value).Take(2).ToArray();
}
else
{
    _currentEnabled = EyeButtonArray.OrderBy(i => Random.value).Take(2).ToArray();
}
```

See

- [`IEnumerable.Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except)